# How to create a random name picker? Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to be able to create a random name selector, that allows you to input the names you want and then it randomly chooses one of these. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Add whatever your tries/code.

Comment: Create an **Array** of the names then use `Math.random()` to pick a random number that is a position within the array, that position holds your randomly selected name. Try something and [**update**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61537219/edit) your question with code that we can try helping to fix.

Comment: no, create a vector. arrays are old talk.